# Getting 404 when switching to production with yii framework

Tags: php, yii, http-status-code-404, production-environment

i'm using yii framework to develop, everything works fine when i was in development.

This morning I added a new route and push it to the server but i can't access it, i got a 404 page not found. I try to change access rules to make it accessible by every one but nothing change, still 404.
I m trying to access to update method via this url: index.php?r=adminuser/update&id=5

Here is the code of the controller:

```
class AdminUserController extends Controller {

  public function filters()
  {
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
    );
  }

  public function accessRules()
  {
    return array(
        array('allow', 
            'actions' => array('index', 'create', 'update'),
            'users'   => array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', 
            'actions' => array('admin', 'delete'),
            'roles'   => array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny', // deny all users
            'users' => array('*'),
        ),
    );
  }
  public function actionUpdate($id)
  {
   $model=$this->loadModel($id);

   if(isset($_POST['AdminUser']))
     $model->save($_POST['AdminUser'])
   $this->render('update',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
  }
}
```

Thanks you for those who can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your url should be like `index.php?r=adminUser/update&id=5`

Comment: People have to authentificate before updating data, in dev mode it works perfectly.
But i also tried your solution, still 404.

I was wondering, are the accessrules overwriting automatically, or have i to force it ?